# Referencing current list inside list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

*Apologies if the title makes no sense.

I am trying create a new list, which contains elements from list `a` that are also found in list `b` (without duplicates).

My current code works, except it includes duplicates. What I am trying to do (see below) throws an error message. I know why it is not working, but is there a way to get around this, while keeping the code on one line?

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]


# What I have currently
list2 = [num for num in a if num in b]

print(list2)
```

> [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]

```
# What I am trying to do
list2 = [num for num in a if num in b and num not in list2]

print(list2)
```

> NameError: name 'list2' is not defined

Comment: Use sets, much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) here, because:

> Set objects support mathematical operations like union, intersection, difference, and symmetric difference

```
In [38]: a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
    ...: b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
    ...:

In [39]: set(a) & set(b)
Out[39]: {1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a great help. How does this work exactly? I came across sets, but don't quite understand them. Is there only purpose to remove duplicates from a list?

Comment: @Polar_Py Sets are just unordered collections without duplicate elements.  The intersection of two sets (elements found in both sets) is also a set, so it will not contain duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve this would be to use `sets` and the `intersection` method.

```
>>> a = set([1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89])
>>> b = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13])
>>> a.intersection(b)
    set([1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13])
```

Edit: Chris beat me to it :)

Comment: Thanks anyway! If I wanted to convert a set to a list, would I just do mylist = list(myset)?

Comment: Yep! `list(a)` will transform `a` back into a list.